# ooVoo Android SDK get a list of connected users

Tags: android, oovoo

I'm trying ooVoo video chat SDK because I need to integrate video chat into my Android app and everything's working fine except that I can't figure out how to get a list of connected users.

I can make a call to a user if I enter its ID but what if I don't know it? I'd like to create a popup with a list of connected users so I can select one and make a video call but don't know how to do it. Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself in case it is useful to anyone else. You simply can't with SDK, I have contacted tech support at ooVoo and they told me you have to implement such a functionality by yourself and this is what I've done, using AWS to store connected users I can show a popup.